# Browser shows blank page in Magento

Tags: magento

I am getting an blank page while loading the Magento homepage, i.e. browser display is blank. It seems that I am facing some error.

What should I do to overcome this?

Comment: Are there any js errors? Have you checked your var/log folder?  What have you tried so far.

Comment: magento write log file in /var directory, do you have a error log ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please go to the Magento root folder, find `index.php`, open it, find the following line and uncomment it (remove the `#`), then save the file.

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

You should see errors in the Browser now. Hope this helps you.

Comment: it worked, it was of syntax error in some phtml file.. thanks

Comment: I also had to change a setting in the Magento database to get logging to start working. In the table `core_config_data`, I changed `dev/log/active` from `0` to `1`. In my case, the problem was extra newline characters at the end of the `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/unsecure/base_url` settings in `core_config_data`.